# CPU stuck for 23s 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 on MSI gl62 6qd It has been running okay for few days. Now i have this error, if i run ubuntu in recovery mode it runs normally but graph drivers is Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe instead of nvidia drivers.

Comment: Checked os and app logs?

Comment: i am not familiar with logs. What should i look for?

Comment: Where are the logs? google that. what in them? words like error exception, fatal, warning ...

Comment: i did not see anything special in log. I decided to install new kernel: 4.6 and it works now.